# React material UI Select box onBlur event not working

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using react and react material to my application. I have used select box for getting some values. If I open the selectbox, the close was not working. For that, I have decided to use `onBlur` event. Please see the code below

```
const handleBlur = () => {
    setIsOpen(false);
  }

<Select
        multiple
        MenuProps={{ PaperProps: { className: classes.menu } }}
        open={isOpen}
        onOpen={handleOpen}
        onChange={handleChange}
        onBlur={handleBlur}
        margin="dense"
        variant={variant}
        input={inputComponent}
        value={selected}
        // className={classes.select}
        inputProps={{
          classes: {
              icon: classes.icon,
          }
        }}
        renderValue={elements => (
          <div className={classes.chips}>
            {(elements as string[]).map(value => {
              return (
                <Chip
                  style={{ backgroundColor: `#${ColorUtils.getColor(value)}` }}
                  key={value}
                  label={value}
                  className={`-select ${classes.chip}`}
                />
              );
            })}
          </div>
        )}
      >
```

In this case, the blur was not working. Could anyone please help to fix this problem

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Material UI's Select component doesn't have `onBlur` prop. Try `onClose` instead.
https://material-ui.com/api/select/#props

Comment: Please elaborate